# How to properly overload '+' operator for a struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'd like to overload the '+' operator for A `struct` but I'm getting compiler warning
Here's my attempt :

```
struct wektor{
    int x;
    int y=0;    
    int norm(){
        return x*x+y*y;
    }
};

wektor& operator +(wektor &a,wektor &b){
    wektor c;
    c.x=a.x+b.x;  // 12 line - warning here
    c.y=a.y+b.y;
    return c;
};
```

Compiler warning:

> [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]  in 12 line

Comment: is struct `wektor{` line 0?

Comment: Why don't you read the error message ?

Comment: Should `wektor` be`vector`?  And why does `norm()` calculate the magnitude squared, instead of having anything to do with normalization?

Comment: @Mooing Duck "magnitude squared" - yes but it doesn't matter, `wektor` is `vector` in my native language, but it supposed not to be C++ vector, but mathematical one, first in 2d version, so I've called it this way

Comment: Oh, I'd only heard it as a mispronounciation before, but I see now that that's how the Poles spell it at least.  My bad.  I deduced it was a math vector, but was confused when `norm` had nothing to do with  math vector normaliation.

Comment: @Mooing Duck http://www.ivona.com/pl  type "wektor" and push play to hear how it sounds in polish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, binary operator+ should return a new value, not a reference. And if implemented in terms of references as input, these should be const:

```
wektor operator +(const wektor &a, const wektor &b);
```

Second, the warning is about this initialization:

```
struct wektor{
    int x;
    int y=0;    // HERE! C++11 only
    int norm(){
        return x*x+y*y;
    }
};
```

You can only do this in C++11. You could use a constructor in C++03.

```
struct wektor{
    wector() : y() {} // zero-initializes y
    int x;
    int y;
    int norm(){ return x*x+y*y;}
};
```

Going back to the `operator+`, I would implement an member `operator+=`, and then use it in a non-member `operator+`:

```
wektor operator +(wektor a, const wektor &b)
{
  return a+= b;
}
```

Alternatively, give `wector` a two parameter constructor for `x` and `y`:

```
wector(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
```

ant then

```
wektor operator + (const wektor& a, const wektor &b)
{
  return wector(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}
```

Comment: your answer is very good, could you tell me how to overload `+` to make validate the operation  `w+5` where `w` is a `wektor` ?

Comment: @Qbik either provide an `wector operator+` that takes a `wector` and an `int` as arguments (but then `5+w` wouldn't work) or provide an (implicit) converting constructor for `wector` that takes an `int` as parameter: `wector(int x) : x(x), y(0) {}`.

Answer (score 8):

The warning is telling you about the line:

```
int y=0;
```

You can't have an initialiser on a non-static non-const member prior to C++11. If you want to initialise `y` to 0 then you have to provide a constructor for `wektor` with a member initialization list.

Nonetheless, your `operator+` parameters should be of type `const wektor&`. It should also return by value, because at the moment you're returning a reference to a local object that will be destroyed at the end of the function, and that is bad. It should look like this:

```
wektor operator +(const wektor &a, const wektor &b){
    wektor c;
    c.x=a.x+b.x;  // 12 line - warning here
    c.y=a.y+b.y;
    return c;
};
```

Comment: without `y=0` I've got: "[Warning] reference to local variable 'c' returned [enabled by default]"

Comment: @Qbik do both changes - this & not returning by reference.

Comment: @Qbik You shouldn't return a reference to a local variable. The local variable goes out of scope and is destroyed. So then the reference is left dangling.

Answer (score 2):

Not like that. The signature should be

```
wektor operator +(const wektor &a, const wektor &b)
```

I.e. don't return by reference from the `+` operator, and, even more importantly, don't return a temporary by reference.

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning that you're using a feature from C++11, which isn't available in previous C++ standards.

When you know that what you've programed works the way you think, you can
get rid of this error by doing:

If you're using CodeBlocks:

1. Right-Click "Build Options..."
2. Select the "Other Options" tab
3. Add "-std=gnu++11"

If you're using the command line:
Add "-std=gnu++11" to the command arg's.

Comment: Really? Weeeeeird. Why do they bother with the warning then? Why do you need to enable "C++11"?

Comment: On g++, `-std=c++0x` for versions older than 4.7, and `-std=c++11` since then (`-std=c++0x` works too). For other compilers, I don't know.